# how do you open up your recent ruby rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was following a tutorial and it was late, so I closed everything (command line, textmate) and now when I want to work on my project again I do not know how to open it back up in command line or get back in it and launch the rails server.

Comment: `mate .`? `rails s`? How about you look at the tutorial again?

Comment: hey i'm learning, I have looked at the tutorial but it does not mention about shutting down the project and opening it back up. If I did not need help I wouldn't be posting a question here

Comment: I'd suggest taking a step back, then, and at least figure out how to edit files. It must have told you how to start the server; that won't have changed. Did you install bundler and run `bundle install`? What version of Rails are you using? How old is the tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

cd into your project directory

```
mate .

rails s
```

Should get you right back where you were

Comment: I cd'd into the project and ran rails s and got this

Comment: >Could not find gem 'pg (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
>Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Comment: just run bundle install: bundle install

Comment: I did run bundle install and I got this >gem install pg -v '0.13.2
and when I run it, it gives me nothing
>ERROR:  While executing gem ... (ArgumentError)
    Illformed requirement ["0.13.2\n\ngem install pg -v 0.13.2"]

But I got that error though